# Decoding a binary tree from a string

Tags: string, encoding, binary-tree, pseudocode

Given a binary tree as a string, I am supposed to write a pseudo-code program that decodes that string into a binary tree implemented as a linked list, like so:

```
  struct binaryTree  
  {  
      Node *root
  }

  struct Node  
  {  
     char info;  
     Node* left;  
     Node* right;  
  }
```

Example:

string = "A(B,C(D(E,F),$))"
  The tree would look like this:

```
             A
         B       C
              D   
            E   F
```

I've tried recursion, single stack and double stack solutions, all of them have failed. How should I proceed?

the particular encoding is like this:

',' separates the left and right children
'(' means next level
')' means previous level
'$' means NULL node

Comment: _I've tried ..., all of them have failed_ - post the best attempt and ask for some specific help on that. Right now you're asking us to do your homework.

Comment: My best attempt was to iterate the string and put the literals in a stack. When a ')' is found, pop 2 elements of the stack and add them to a queue. After the stack is empty, rebuild the tree using the queue. However, this does not build the tree correctly, as for example, if string = "A(B(X,Y),C(D(E,F),Z))" then X and Y would be added on the last level of the tree, not as children to the B node. I believe I should have specified that this is not homework, I am just trying to do some self research. I have worked with trees before using some high end algorithms, but I am just blocked here.

Comment: Sounds way too complicated. You shouldn't need a Stack or a Queue, just a little recursive parser. Also, get rid of that Tree{} type. A Node IS a Tree.

Comment: It's just a elegance trick I find myself requiring very often in order to better visualize the code. I'll try to write a recursive parser and will post back if I get stuck again. Truth be told, I don't understand why I am getting stuck at such simple things, considering the fact that I'm easily doing advanced stuff, like NLP parsers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428581/building-parse-tree-from-prefixed-expression-in-c